# Unclear on how to enter and setup the RAID BIOS on a GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD5H LGA 1155

Tags: bios, raid

I have two [Samsung 850 Pro 256GB](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-7KE256BW) SSD’s hooked up to a [GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD5H LGA 1155](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4139#ov).

When I enter BIOS, it shows that I have two of the drives connected, and I have my SATA mode selection set to RAID.

I didn’t do anything else, but from what I’m reading I shouldn't have to. I never get any option that was different from what I saw before I switched from AHCI mode.

I restarted and tried holding <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> in every possible combination without ever getting the option to go into the RAID BIOS. Did I miss doing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specs for the [GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD5H LGA 1155](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4139#ov) shows RAID being mentioned in the “GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response” technology. Then looking at [the page detailing “GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response” technology](http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/282/ez-smart-response.html) explains; emphasis is mine:

> **About GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response**
>
> The GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response utility is a simple application that
>   allows users to quickly and easily configure their system for Intel®
>   Smart Response Technology. **In the past, enabling Intel® Smart Response
>   meant users needed to enter the BIOS in order to configure their
>   system for RAID mode, which then required a complete reinstall of the
>   operating system. Once that processes was complete, users then needed
>   to install the Intel® Rapid Storage Utility as well as configure
>   Intel's Smart Response Technology. GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response does all
>   of this automatically, without users having to perform a complicated
>   install process.** This allows them to quickly and effortlessly enjoy a
>   significant boost in system performance.

And [looking at this download page](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/Utility.aspx) shows:

> **EZ Smart Response Technology**
>
> - **Version:** B11.0714.1
> - **Date:** 2011/07/15

So to my eyes, it seems like the “GIGABYTE EZ Smart Response” utility is the key to solving this issue on your side.